# How to get value from each datatable row dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm working with Datatable. The problem is I need to get all the values from each row's dropdownlist. The datatable have the column 'Company' which the user need to select value from dropdownlist .Now I'm able to get each row's value for **Citizen_ID** and **Tel** using the code below.

```
var rowData = table.rows().data(); 
var dataArr = [];
$.each($(rowData), function(key,value){ //data                     
        let tempObj = {
        Citizen_id: value["Citizen_ID"],
        Tel: value["Tel"]
       }
  dataArr.push(tempObj);
});
```

[image]

How can I get selected value from dropdownlist for all datatable pages?.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in a slightly different way.

Some of the data you need can be accessed from the DataTable, but the selected value in each row's drop-down list only exists in the DOM, so you need the related DOM node to access that data.

I would therefore populate the following two variables, at the start:

```js
var rowData = table.rows().data().toArray(); 
var rowNodes = table.rows().nodes().toArray();
```

Both of these are populated using DataTables API calls, so the entire table is processed.

This gives you two arrays - one with the DataTables data objects for each row, and the other with the DOM nodes.

Then you can use a traditional `for` loop to iterate the arrays in parallel, and extract the specific pieces of data you need.

For the drop-down node, you can use a jQuery selector:

```js
let selectedCompany = $(rowNodes[i]).find("select.company option:selected").text();
```

I used a class (value = `company`) in the HTML code for the `select`, just in case there are multiple different selects in one row.

Here is a demo of the overall approach:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    </table>
    
    <br>
    
     <button id="data_btn" type="button">Get Data</button> 

</div>

<script>

var dataSet = [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    }
  ];

$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  lengthMenu: [ [2, -1] , [2, "All"] ],
  data: dataSet,
  columns: [
    { title: "ID", data: "id" },
    { title: "Name", data: "name" },
    { title: "Office", data: "office" },
    { title: "Position", data: "position" },
    { title: "Company",
      defaultContent: '',
      render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        if (type === 'display') {
          return '<select class="company">' 
              + '<option value="Google">Google</option>' 
              + '<option value="Microsoft">Microsoft</option>' 
              + '<option value="Amazon">Amazon</option></select>';
        } else {
          return data;
        }
      }
    },
    { title: "Start date", data: "start_date" },
    { title: "Extn.", data: "extn" },
    { title: "Salary", data: "salary" }
  ]

} ); 

$("#data_btn").on( "click", function() {
  var rowData = table.rows().data().toArray(); 
  var rowNodes = table.rows().nodes().toArray(); 

  var dataArr = [];  
  for (i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
    let selectedCompany = $(rowNodes[i]).find("select.company option:selected").text();
    let tempObj = {
      id: rowData[i].id,
      name: rowData[i].name,
      company: selectedCompany
    }
    dataArr.push(tempObj);
  }
  console.log( dataArr );
});

} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When you run the demo, first select a "company" value in each of the drop-downs.

Then click the "Get Data" button.

The resulting object will look similar to the following:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "company": "Amazon"
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "Donna Snider",
    "company": "Microsoft"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @andrewjames for the clear explanation and example code here. I actually stuck at this because I didn't know that  the selected value in each row's drop-down list only exists in the DOM. So that's mean I can't access its value using something like value[Company] right?. I will try your solution and provide a feedback later. Thank you.

Comment: Any time you have data entry fields in your table (e.g. via a `<select>` field or an `<input>` field, or checkboxes, and so on... in those cases, any data entered by the user does not exist in the underlying DataTables object (JavaScript) - it only exists in the page DOM. You can, of course, provide initial values for such field when you create the DataTable, (when it is first displayed). You can also add event listeners which will detect user input and save that input to the DataTable - but that is a whole different question.